Zig for loop range iterator with custom int type
I am using a for loop to iterate over an integer range such as:
for (0..256) |i| {

My issue is that I need i to be of type u21, but it is currently usize.  I can just hit it with the manual @intCast inside the loop, but I was wondering if there is a better way.
I was hoping the following would work, but it still gives me a usize:
for (@as(u21, 0)..256) |i| {

Any suggestions to elegantly accomplish this?

The documentation doesn't mention any tricks. But you can use a while loop:
var i: u21 = 0;
while (i < 256) : (i += 1) {
    // ...
}


Accepted as I think this is a fine answer.  But would be nice to have the control in the for loop.  Maybe a language improvement to raise somewhere?
